# jquery animation differs when using webkit - other browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm having a bit of a problem with a site where the splashscreen transitions perfectly in webkit based browsers, but when using firefox or IE9 (no IE8 requirement luckily enough), he first does the color transition on the background and afterwards the scrolling part.

http://acad-emo.n8e.be and click on NL in the logo.

```
$('#NL').click(function () {
  $('#menu').animate({opacity: 1},2000);                
  $('html').animate({backgroundColor: '#b8c48a'},2000);                
  ShowDiv('acad_emo');
});
```

In that function the important parts are:

```
$.scrollTo($('#acad_emo'), scrollspeed, { offset: { top: TopPos, left: LPos} }, { easing: 'easeInOutCubic ' });
History.pushState({page:'acad_emo'}, "Acad-Emo", "#!page=acad_emo");
```

I was thinking that the problem might be that the scrolling part was done in a separate function, but after copying the relevant code and replacing the Showdiv() function call i still get the same effect where both FF and IE do the scrolling after the color transition.

Anyone who could shed some light on what is going wrong here?

Comment: What does the other function look like? I need it to see what the problem is

Comment: The scrollto plugin is this one: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: You don't really need the scrollTo plugin because you could just use jquery, and make this manually

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
$.scrollTo($('#acad_emo'), scrollspeed, { offset: { top: TopPos, left: LPos} }, { easing: 'easeInOutCubic ' }); History.pushState({page:'acad_emo'}, "Acad-Emo", "#!page=acad_emo");
```

to this:

```
$.scrollTo($('#acad_emo'), scrollspeed, { offset: { top: TopPos, left: LPos} }, { easing: 'easeInOutCubic ' }); History.pushState({page:'acad_emo'}, "Acad-Emo", "#!page=acad_emo").delay(2000);
```

I'm not sure, if you know better, but what I'm trying to do is to delay the scrolling, using .delay(time), this should stop it from coming in to early, if I'm right...

Comment: Oh, but i'm not trying to delay the scrolling, the way it's done in Chrome, where the scrolling and the color transition are done at the same time is the way i'd like it to be in the other browsers :)

Comment: Then I assume it's an issue with either the plugin or the seperate function but since you already tested the whole seperate function thing I blame the plugin, just out of curiousity what happens when you place the link to the function above the two animations? Does it then scroll first?

Comment: just did a quick test on my local machine, yes, then it scrolls first.

Comment: try putting the 2 animations inside the function with the scrollTo

Comment: will do so friday afternoon, then i have time planned to work on it again :)